# Accessing Service With SelfSigned Certificate Using GSOAP

Tags: c++, openssl, gsoap

I have a Service deployed on a Server which is Signed using self signed certificate.

I am currently able to access the service using

`````````````````````````````````
if (soap_ssl_client_context(&soap,
                SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION,
                NULL , NULL,
                NULL,  /* ``    ````````````````````````````````    ``*/
                NULL,NULL )!= SOAP_OK)
    {
`````````````````````````````````

But i guess in this case my backend server can be replaced and my client will still work because i wont be doing any cert validation.

To Do it right in Prod how can i import the Self signed certs and how can i pass them through GSOAP to validate the certs, so i can make sure that i am connecting to right host. Any code Examples are highly appreciated as i am bit new with Gsoap , openSSL & C++

Comment: C or C++? Choose one.

Comment: Sorry Jonathon... now corrected i need it in c++ ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openssl s_client -connect : -showcerts < /dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM > .pem

This Did it